# different hash algorithm for controllers

Tags: cakephp, authentication, cakephp-2.0

How to change CakePHP **2.0** AuthComponent hash algorithm?
And, How to set different algorithm for different controllers (for example, `users` uses sha1 and `customers` uses md5)

I've read [that article](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1254/Change-Hash-Function), but when I tested it in my cakephp **2.0** app, it said:

```
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type User as array in *******\lib\Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent.php on line 661
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That article would have worked for version 1.3, but it looks like they've upgraded the AuthComponent. You can read all about it here http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/authentication.html?highlight=authentication

About half-way down the page they describe how you can set up your own custom hashing function as a beforeSave. For your situation, you would define the beforeSave of your User model to use the SHA1 algorithm, and so on for each different model.